# How can I generate multiple ssh keys for a new Ansible server?

Tags: linux, ansible, ssh-keys, automation

I work on an on-premise network, and we have an Ansible server connected via SSH-Keys to around 400 servers.
I've wanted to recreate the Ansible VM, due to the fact that it was poorly made on top of the fact that it is on an unstable, soon to be out of service data-center.

What is the best way to get those 400~ servers to work with the new Ansible server via SSH-Keys?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy the private ssh key from the old server to the new server and configure Ansible to use that key.

Comment: And how can I do that exactly?

Comment: per default ssh keys are stored under `/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa` That is the key your new server would need to authenticated against the hosts.